# No IUserTokenProvider is registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I recently updated `Asp.Net Identity Core` of my application form 1.0 to 2.0.

There are new features which I wanted to try like `GenerateEmailConfirmationToken`, etc.

I'm using [this](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Identity/Identity-PasswordPolicy/Identity-PasswordPolicy/Controllers/AccountController.cs) project as a reference.

When the user tries to register, I get error during the execution of Post method of Register

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;     

public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var ifUserEXists = _userManager.FindByName(model.EmailId);
        if (ifUserEXists == null) return View(model);
        var confirmationToken = _userRepository.CreateConfirmationToken();//this is how i'm generating token currently.                
        var result = _userRepository.CreateUser(model,confirmationToken);
        var user = _userManager.FindByName(model.EmailId);
        if (result)
        {
            var code = _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);//error here
            _userRepository.SendEmailConfirmation(model.EmailId, model.FirstName, confirmationToken);
            //Information("An email is sent to your email address. Please follow the link to activate your account.");
            return View("~/Views/Account/Thank_You_For_Registering.cshtml");
        }     
    }
    
    //Error("Sorry! email address already exists. Please try again with different email id.");
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Resource.AccountController_Register_Sorry__User_already_exists__please_try_again_);
    return View(model);
}
```

In the line

```
 var code = _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
```

I get error saying:

```
No IUserTokenProvider is registered.
```

For now, I just wanted to see what kind of code it generates.
Is there some change I need to make to my `ApplicationUser` class that inherits from `IdentityUser` class?

Or is there something I need to change to get those function work?

Comment: Is there any way you can check if a user exists based on other fields than the email address? For instance if i had two fields called CustomerNumber and Postcode for users who would already pre exist in the database to stop just anyone from registering

Comment: You can refer to this S.O answer which takes care of this error and updates the password for the identity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78104147/1807452

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You have to specify a `UserTokenProvider` to generate a token.

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
// ...

var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("SampleAppName");

var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>());

userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(
    provider.Create("SampleTokenName"));
```

You should also read this article: [Adding Two Factor Authentication to an Application Using ASP.NET Identity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/02/18/adding-two-factor-authentication-to-an-application-using-asp-net-identity.aspx).

Comment: what are `"Sample"` and `"EmailConfirmation"`? some text that can be anything?

Comment: "Sample"=AppName, "EmailConfirmation"=purpose (like the parameter names)

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to use the same for generating and validating tokens

Comment: The link is OK. You put this code where you initialize the `UserManager`

Comment: this causes 'Could not load type 'System.Security.Cryptography.DpapiDataProtector' from assembly  in .netcore

Comment: Kind of surprised that 5 years later, the asp.net core docs still provide no helpful information that guides you to use this properly...

Answer (score 37):

In ASP.NET Core it's nowadays possible to configure a default service in the Startup.cs like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

There is no need to call the `DpapiDataProtectionProvider`or anything like that. The DefaultTokenProviders() will take care of the call to GenerateEmailConfirmationToken from the UserManager.

Comment: That line save 2 hours of my time... thnak you .

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the accepted answer, I'd like to add that this approach will not work in Azure Web-Sites, you'd get CryptographicException instead of a token.

To get it fixed for Azure, implement your own IDataProtector: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23661872/809357)

Slightly more detail in [blog-post](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-and-cryptographicexception-when-running-your-site-on-microsoft-azure-web-sites/)

Answer (score 16):

**My solution :**

```
    var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("YourAppName");
    UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, string>(provider.Create("UserToken")) 
        as IUserTokenProvider<User, string>;
```

**My problem with this code solved.**
**Good luck friends.**

Comment: using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;

Comment: I had to use DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser, string> instead of <User, string> for both generics. Also the userId in GeneratePasswordResetToken is the guid string Id and not the userName or Email.

Answer (score 10):

In case anyone else makes the same mistake that I did. I tried to make a function like the one below and sure enough the error "No IUserTokenProvider is registered." was gone. However as soon as I tried to use the link generated from "callbackUrl" I got the error "Invalid token." In order for it to work you need to get the HttpContext UserManager. If you are using a standard ASP.NET MVC 5 application with individual user accounts you can do it like below..

Code that works:

```
public ActionResult Index()
     {
         //Code to create ResetPassword URL
         var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
         var user = userManager.FindByName("useremail@gmail.com");
         string code = userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
         var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
         return View();
     }
```

First try that does not work, `No IUserTokenProvider is registered.` is gone but the URL created gets `Invalid token.`.

```
public ActionResult NotWorkingCode()
     {
             //DOES NOT WORK - When used the error "Invalid token." will always trigger.
             var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("ApplicationName");
             var userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
             userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
             var user = userManager.FindByName("useremail@gmail.com");
             string code = userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
             var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
             //DOES NOT WORK - When used the error "Invalid token." will always trigger.
         return View();
     }
```

Comment: Worked in web api controller too, just needed to use HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()

Answer (score 6):

As per pisker above

In startup.cs you can use

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In .net core 2.0 you may need to add to the startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
```

This worked fine for me.

Comment: I think that's important to remember that this is a Asp .NET Core solution, it will not work with Asp .NET Framework.

Answer (score 6):

While modifying .NET Core's Identity files, I stumbled upon this error:

> NotSupportedException: No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider named
>   'Default' is registered.

The

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync

function couldn't generate a token because no provider was available upon registering a new user. This error has an easy fix though!

If you're like me, you changed `AddDefaultIdentity` in the `Startup.cs` file to `AddIdentity`. I wanted to implement my own user that inherited from the base user. By doing this I lost the default token providers. The fix was to add them back with `AddDefaultTokenProviders()`.

```
        services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

After that fix, everything worked again!

source: https://mattferderer.com/NotSupportedException-No-IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider-tuser-named-default-registered

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after updating Identity, and found that it was because I was using Unity.

See this question thread on the solution:
[Register IAuthenticationManager with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731426/register-iauthenticationmanager-with-unity)

Also below for quick reference:

> Here is what I did to make Unity play nice with ASP.NET Identity 2.0:
>
> I added the following to the `RegisterTypes` method in the `UnityConfig` class:
>
> ```
> container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
> container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
> container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
> container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
> ```

Comment: I followed this, but it didn't work (for `GeneratePasswordResetToken` -- but got the same error of "No IUserTokenProvider is registered"). After adding `container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(
                new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()));` to `UnityConfig.cs`, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be intrested in looking here:
[How to implement a TokenProvider in ASP.NET Identity 1.1 nightly build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539579/how-to-implement-a-tokenprovider-in-asp-net-identity-1-1-nightly-build)
to use the default token provider implementation from Microsoft.Identity.Owin package

Answer (score 0):

in IdentityConfig.cs, Add your twofactor option:

```
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        //config sms service 
        manager.SmsService = new Services.SMS();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be useful for ASP.NET Framework (with simple sync task):

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
...

var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
var user = userManager.FindByName(MyUserNameTextBox.Text);

var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName());
userManager.UserTokenProvider = (IUserTokenProvider<IdentityUser, string>)(new DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser, string>(provider.Create("UserToken")) as IUserTokenProvider<IdentityUser, string>);

var token = userManager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
var result = userManager.ResetPassword(user.Id, token, MyPasswordTextBox.Text);
```