# Web Api Owin - Forgot password

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I am trying to follow "Forget my password" routine on Web API. I am creating a link using `GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` on WebAPI and send by email, and user change password on MVC side.

I tried several examples of you guys, but all of them generate me a bigger code then is generated on MVC side and when I try to change my password using the WebAPI generated link it said that code is wrong.

Earlier, I got `usermanager` by DI, but when I use on **AzureServer**, they cause me an error

> "ExceptionMessage": "The data protection operation was unsuccessful.
>   This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for
>   the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the
>   thread is impersonating.".

Localhost works fine.

What I suppose to do? I'm stuck for 3 days. Please, help!

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/45451168/3358570?

Comment: no, I'll try when I come back home! Thanx @TalhaJunaid

Comment: Awesome @TalhaJunaid! It works very fine!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The data protection operation was unsuccessful on Azure using OWIN / Katana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773651/the-data-protection-operation-was-unsuccessful-on-azure-using-owin-katana)