# Configure machineKey from ARM templates for asp.net web api project

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-rm-template

I need to use the same machine key for different asp.net web api applications (deployed on the different servers on azure).

I can set it via web.config (machine key) sections. 
But I would like to set it via ARM templates (azure).

Automation script in azure has machineKey property at the Microsoft.Web/sites/config resource (but it is null).
Site template reference doesn't have machineKey property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites

So I assume that I can't set it via arm (I tried without success, so for now I take it from app settings [How to set machineKey on Azure Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595034/how-to-set-machinekey-on-azure-website))
Does anyone know how to set machineKey section from azure templates?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge, it is not possible.

Azure template is used to give web app settings. You could use template to set Web App's name, node version, javaContainer,etc.. **However, given the machine key is not an app setting - it's under the system.web section of the web.config.**

I also check Web App template's resource, it does not provides such configuration.