# High Availability ASP.Net MVC on Azure Web App throwing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, high-availability, web-farm, machinekey

We have one ASP.Net Pure MVC application (.Net MVC and jQuery). But due to traffic increasing clients wanted to move on HADR (High Availability Disaster Recovery) using Microsoft Azure Web App. So we have deployed the same on 2 different Web App by going through the link https://codewithshadman.com/machine-key-generator/ and also link [Adding machineKey to web.config on web-farm sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855666/adding-machinekey-to-web-config-on-web-farm-sites)

Post following above links, we are using the same Machine Key for these 2 Web Apps. But when we hit the HADR URL we landed to Login Page but when hit on Login Button post entered Username and password, under the web development tool in Google Chrome, we see the error 'Internal Server Error (500)'.

So anyone have idea how to setup the same for Azure Web App?

Comment: Is it asp.net core or the old asp.net 4.x? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/choose-aspnet-framework?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT, It is .Net Framework 4.5. Yes it is ASP.Net 4.x

Comment: What is the exception you are seeing in error log? 500 is too generic to know what is going wrong. Also, I assume along with sharing machine key you also have setup out of proc state store since your app is now distributed? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178586(v=vs.100)

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT, exact error is: "The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present." We have the SQL Server Session which is out of proc state, correct? OR do I need to set somewhere "Out of Proc State"?

Comment: SQL is fine. It's out of proc. I will check on the error part.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT, do i need to add anything in web.config file in this case like, <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
      sqlConnectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;data 
        source=SampleSqlServer;" /> ?

Comment: yes, you need to configure SessionState in web.config. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/configure-sql-store-session-state

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT, Is there any way to access the Machine Key at MVC Controller? I am not asking reading the Machine Key from configuration. Reason from asking this, I doubt Azure is not using the Machine Key which we have configured through the Web.Config file so like to cross check by accessing the Machine Key at Runtime and wanted to compare with configured one.

Comment: Ahh I see. No you cannot read the machine key used by the app from code. But you seem to be right that the machine key from web.config is not respected. So can you try overriding at app start up as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765371/13791953 There are many upvotes in that answer.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT, Currently I am doing exactly the same way mentioned in that Post. Either way, it is throwing the same error. Going through Web.config way OR Global.asax way.

Comment: Regarding the session state part of the earlier comment, were you able to set it up correctly with SQL?

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT, Yes. I used this: <sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="Server=tcp:SQLServerDetailsHere,1433;Database=DatabaseNameHere;User ID=databaseUserNameHere;Password=PasswordHere;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="20000" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" />,  and I have two tables in this database 1.ASPStateTempApplications and 2. ASPStateTempSessions