# ASP .net WebForm Identity have problem in reset password. The data protection operation was unsuccessful

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm working on an asp.net webform application and recently we add identity to it. Every thing was good till we add the ability of resetting the users password to admin privilege. In local system and debug mode this process is done with no error but when we move the published version to server an error raises that is : **The data protection operation was unsuccessful. This may have been caused by not having the user profile loaded for the current thread's user context, which may be the case when the thread is impersonating.**

Thank you for helping me to solve this problem.

The code that we use is like this:

```cs
var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("IdentityProvider");
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new IdentityDbContext(SetCnnConnection()));
var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
manager.PasswordHasher = new Hasher();
manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
var user = manager.FindByName(userName);            
var token = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
password = GenerateRandomPassword(null);
var result = manager.ResetPassword(user.Id, token, password);
message = result.Errors.ToList();
return result == IdentityResult.Success;
```

Comment: You seem to be lacking code.

Comment: The code is added.

Comment: To confirm: this is ASP.NET and not ASP.NET Core, right?

Comment: Yes,ASP.net Web Form

Comment: At the end I find out what is the problem. Accourding this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30661014/getting-an-error-while-going-to-reset-password?rq=2 the problem is setting in IIS application pool.