# MVC Repository, Unity, Identity Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container, dapper, asp.net-identity-2

I'm starting a new project using MVC 5, Identity 2.x, Unity, and Dapper.  I'm using the standard EF functionality for Identity but using Dapper for the rest of the DB access.  I'm using a Repository Pattern for all my (non-Identity) DB calls.

I'm fairly new to Unity and Dapper but keep gettin a "***Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***" error whenever I make a call to the DB interface in the Account Controller line from below:

```
var result = _companyaccountrepository.AddToCompanyUsers(model);
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

**Account Controller**

```
private ICompanyAccountRepository _companyaccountrepository { get; set; }

public ICompanyAccountRepository companyaccountrepository
{
    get { return _companyaccountrepository ?? (_companyaccountrepository = new CompanyAccountRepository());  }
}

private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}


private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    private set { _signInManager = value; }
}

public AccountController()
{

}

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ICompanyAccountRepository companyaccountrepository)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
    _companyaccountrepository = companyaccountrepository;
}

...

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SignUp(RegisterUserAndCompanyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        user.FirstName = model.FirstName;
        user.LastName = model.LastName;

        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {

            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

            var result = _companyaccountrepository.AddToCompanyUsers(model);   //*** THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS ****

            return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");

        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

**Interface/Dapper SQL (dummy code to make it simple)**

```
public interface ICompanyAccountRepository
{
    CompanyUser AddToCompanyUsers(RegisterUserAndCompanyViewModel user);

}


public class CompanyAccountRepository : ICompanyAccountRepository
{
    private string dbconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    public bool AddToCompanyUsers(RegisterUserAndCompanyViewModel user);
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(dbconn))
        {
            cn.Open();
            cn.Insert(new CompanyUser() { CompanyId = user.companyid, UserId = user.id });
            cn.Close();

        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

**Unity.Config**

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
    // container.LoadConfiguration();

    // TODO: Register your types here

    //12-1-16 Need this for Identity
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>();
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
    container.RegisterType<EmailService>();

    container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
        new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));

    container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(
        new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));


    container.RegisterType<AccountController>(
        new InjectionConstructor(typeof(ApplicationUserManager), typeof(ApplicationSignInManager), typeof(ICompanyAccountRepository)));

    container.RegisterType<AccountController>(
            new InjectionConstructor());


    //Identity / Unity stuff below to fix No IUserToken Issue  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731426/register-iauthenticationmanager-with-unity
    //container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(
    //    new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(
        new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<ICompanyAccountRepository, CompanyAccountRepository>();

}
```

Thanks again for any suggestions.

NOTE: If I add instantiate the repository just before the AddToCompanyUsers call (below), it works fine.  However, this breaks Unity/IOC

```
_companyaccountrepository= new CompanyAccountRepository();
var result = _companyaccountrepository.AddToCompanyUsers(model);
```

Comment: your account controller is simply initialized by default constructor. So _companyaccountrepository is never instantiated

Comment: @simco - thanks for the advice.  I tried removing the default constructor but when I did that, it broke the Identity(via Unity) functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this:

(this should fix your repository error. As for your userManager and signInManager, I believe you can improve how they are configured as well, but that will take to take a look on your startup.auth and your ApplicationDbContext and with all the Identity configuration)

**Account Controller**

```
private readonly ICompanyAccountRepository _companyaccountrepository;// { get; set; } -- remove the getter and setter here



//remove this

// public ICompanyAccountRepository companyaccountrepository
// {
//     get { return _companyaccountrepository ?? (_companyaccountrepository = new CompanyAccountRepository());  }
// }

private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}


private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;

public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
{
    get
    {
        return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    }
    private set { _signInManager = value; }
}

//I think you can remove the parameterless constructor as well
//public AccountController()
//{
//
//}

public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ICompanyAccountRepository companyaccountrepository)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    SignInManager = signInManager;
    _companyaccountrepository = companyaccountrepository;
}

...
```

**EDIT**

Change your constructor to:

```
public AccountController(ICompanyAccountRepository companyaccountrepository)
{
    _companyaccountrepository = companyaccountrepository;
}
```

Comment: With your edit, this appears to be working.  Do I need 2 constructors?  public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ICompanyAccountRepository companyaccountrepository) & public AccountController(ICompanyAccountRepository companyaccountrepository)

Comment: You don't need 2 constructors in this case. You are setting the UserManager and SignInManager as properties separately, so no need for them to be injected at the constructor.