# I cannot reference Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager, why?

Tags: c#, owin, unity-container

I get the following error on my page:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The current type, Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
```

I founded out that I should put this code in `Unityconfig.cs` to resolve this problem:

```
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
            new InjectionFactory(
                o => System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication
            )
        );
```

But the problem is that the IAuthenticationManager is not visible
[image]

although I have added the `Owin.Security` as reference, I have the

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
```

Can you please give me some hints?

Comment: And your referencing the `Microsoft.Owin.Security` dll?

Comment: yes, I have added the reference

Comment: Does it error if you run it? What error do you get? Or will it not build? It could just be intellisense not working correctly.

Comment: It builds the application. When I run and I want to enter on a page, I get the error:The current type, Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManager, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register IAuthenticationManager with Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731426/register-iauthenticationmanager-with-unity)

Comment: [What you have should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26546453/542251). If it doesn't then there is something that your not explaining. If you didn't have the dll referenced then you wouldn't be able to build. I can't see anything in that code to produce the error your saying is happening, so I'm guessing that error is thrown somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.Owin.dll`? As you can see from [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.iauthenticationmanager(v=vs.113).aspx), that is where this interface lives. Worth checking that namespace doesn't always equate to the assembly @Liam :)

Comment: Thank you @DavidG! This was the problem. I just had the reference to Microsoft.Owin.Security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the interface you are trying to use ([`Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.iauthenticationmanager(v=vs.113).aspx)) isn't in `Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll` but is actually in `Microsoft.Owin.dll`. Check the two lines at the top that tell you both the namespace and the assembly. So you just need to add a reference to that assembly.

For situations like this, it's always worth checking the docs as the namespace doesn't always equate to the assembly name.