# How to configure ASP.NET Identity ApplicationUserManager with StructureMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, structuremap, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using asp.net identity in my project and using structuremap as DI framework. the problem is when i use constructor injection then ApplicationUserManager not configured all of it's members e.g TokenProvider, ...

this is my ApplicationUserManager class:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<User, long>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<User, long> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new CustomUserStore(context.Get<InsuranceManagementContext>()));

        // Configure the application user manager
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<User, long>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = false
        };

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequiredLength = 8,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireUppercase = false
        };

        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User, long>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("TEST"));
        }

        return manager;
    }
}
```

this is Startup.Auth class:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(InsuranceManagementContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2.0),
            AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        });
    }
}
```

and its my AccountController:

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

my question is how can i configure my ApplicationUserManager with structuremap?
if i set it as the below code it works but i don't know it is a good solution or not:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
     ...
     x.For<ApplicationUserManager>().Use(() => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>());
     ...
});
```

please hint me if there is a better solution and if it is ok then what is the best lifetime for it? HttpContextScope, Singleton, ...?

Comment: I've just blogged about Identity and DI-containers: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/ this will probably help you.

Answer (score 7):

Before you create the StructureMap configuration for this, it helps to know how you would create it manually, i.e., if you actually "new up" everything yourself.

UserManager has a dependency on IUserStore, and its EntityFramework implementation (UserStore) has a dependency on DbContext.
Doing everything manually would look like this:

```
var dbContext = new IdentityDbContext("Your ConnectionString Name");
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(dbContext);
var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
```

(Replace `IdentityUser` with your custom user, if you are using one)

You can then configure `UserManager` like this:

```
userManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
{
    RequiredLength = 6
};
```

The most complicated part about configuring userManager  is related to the UserTokenProvider (that uses the data protection api), if you would do it manually it would [look like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22629936/no-iusertokenprovider-is-registered):

```
var dataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("Application name");
var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.Create("Purpose");
userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<IdentityUser>(dataProtector);
```

Here's an example of a StructureMap registry (you can extrapolate from this example and adapt it to your own needs):

```
 public DefaultRegistry() {
        Scan(
            scan => {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
            });


        For<IUserStore<IdentityUser>>()
            .Use<UserStore<IdentityUser>>()
            .Ctor<DbContext>()
            .Is<IdentityDbContext>(cfg => cfg.SelectConstructor(() => new IdentityDbContext("connection string")).Ctor<string>().Is("IdentitySetupWithStructureMap"));

        ForConcreteType<UserManager<IdentityUser>>()
            .Configure
            .SetProperty(userManager => userManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6
            })
            .SetProperty(userManager => userManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<IdentityUser>(userManager));                
    }
```

I wrote a blog [post about this](http://www.blinkingcaret.com/2016/03/09/setup-asp-net-identity-using-structuremap/), it explains the process that lead to this configuration, there's also a [link to an example on github of an MVC project](https://github.com/ruidfigueiredo/MvcAndAspNetIdentitySetupWithStructureMapExample) where, using this configuration, you can create, list and delete users.