# ASP.NET MVC: No IUserTokenProvider is registered using Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I am running into the error `No IUserTokenProvider is registered` on a call to `_userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);` which is generating a token to be sent in an account registration e-mail. I have reviewed many posts related to this and none have solved my issue. From what I've learned, this functionality is hooked up in the `ApplicationUserManager` class by the following:

```
if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
{
    IDataProtector dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity");

    this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtector);
}
```

I've attempted to resolve the issue by doing the following as suggested elsewhere: My `ApplicationUserManager` class has teh following signature: 
`public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)`
and the `dataProtectionProvider` I am injecting is bound by Ninject in `Startup.cs` like this:

```
    private IAppBuilder _app;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      _app = app;
      ConfigureAuth(app);
      app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
    }

    private IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
      var kernel = new StandardKernel();
      kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

      //bindings
      kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
      kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

      kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MvcIndividualAuthContext>().InRequestScope();
      kernel.Bind(typeof(IUserStore<>)).To(typeof(UserStore<>)).InRequestScope();
      kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
      kernel.Bind<MvcIndividualAuthContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
      kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string>>().To<ApplicationUserStore>();
      kernel.Bind<ApplicationUserManager>().ToSelf();
      kernel.Bind<ApplicationSignInManager>().ToSelf();
      kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(x => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
      kernel.Bind<IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>>().ToSelf();

      //this bind should be binding the IDataProtectionProvider for my 
      //ApplicationUserManager 
      kernel.Bind<IDataProtectionProvider>().ToMethod(x => _app.GetDataProtectionProvider());


      return kernel;
    }
```

however the binding doesn't seem to be working because my `ApplicationUserManager`'s `UserTokenProvider` is still null at the time of generating my token. For reference, you can find the code for my `ApplicationUserManager` below:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
  {
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
        : base(store)
    {
      // Configure validation logic for usernames
      this.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(this)
      {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
      };

      // Configure validation logic for passwords
      this.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
      {
        RequiredLength = 6,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequireLowercase = true,
        RequireUppercase = true,
      };

      // Configure user lockout defaults
      this.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
      this.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
      this.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

      // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
      // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
      this.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
      {
        MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
      });
      this.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
      {
        Subject = "Security Code",
        BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
      });
      this.EmailService = new EmailService();
      this.SmsService = new SmsService();

      if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
      {
        IDataProtector dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity");

        this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtector);
      }
    }
  }
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471363/no-iusertokenprovider-is-registered-when-using-structuremap-dependency-injecti or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474214/no-iusertokenprovider-is-registered-when-using-dependency-injection help?

Comment: IDataProtectionProvider is injected into my `ApplicationUserManager` and this IDataProtectionProvider provides the `IUserTokenProvider` by teh following two lines in the constructor `IDataProtector dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity");` and `this.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtector);`. The binding is registered in Startup.cs with `kernel.Bind<IDataProtectionProvider>().ToMethod(x => _app.GetDataProtectionProvider());`

Comment: @mjwills unforuntately not, I have reviewed both of those posts numerous times now and am trying to use their solutions to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning and building the solution, the issue has been resolved. Note that the solution had been built numerous times during while the issue was occurring but not cleaned.