# No-iusertokenprovider-is-registered Issue

Tags: c#

Recently I got issue using reset token link in identity core but worked fine by adding AddDefaultTokenProviders() to startup.cs  reference Link https://stackoverflow.com/a/42420009/13126203

Now Issue came when using end points call with user token gives 404 not found error.
the code is startup.cs is as follows

```
 var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUserDomain>();
            var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
            identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
            identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUserDomain>>();

           services.AddIdentity<AppUserDomain,IdentityRole>(options =>{
           options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultProvider;
            })
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above configuration can be simplified and it's solve the issues you having.

```
var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            services.AddDbContext<PrimeTechDbContext>(opt => opt.UseNpgsql(connectionString));
            services.AddIdentity<AppUserDomain, IdentityRole>( options=> {
                options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultProvider;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppUserDomain>()
                .AddSignInManager<AppUserDomain>
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```